# Invalid key length: 16 bytes

Tags: java, android

I am getting Invalid key length: 16 bytes on netbeans ide `keybyte` length is 16

```
SecretKey deskey = new SecretKeySpec(keybyte, "DESede/ECB/NOPADDING");
//enter code here..
Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NOPADDING");
c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey);
```

but the same code works on android

Comment: please share the logs of the error..

Answer (score 5):

Your cipher algorithm (triple DES) is expecting a 24 byte key but you only give it 16 bytes, it might help to show how you build the key.

Also, you should be aware of the limitations of ECB. As identical blocks are always encrypted to the same result, it can leave ciphertexts less opaque than you might assume. [See here for more detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).